# Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/io/HierarchicalStreamDriver in Spring MVC

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat

Im new to Spring, I have just started learning on Spring MVC. I just imported the available small project, but when i run maven on it, it doesn't build successfully. Its throwing the error of

```
1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/io/HierarchicalStreamDriver
```

I have included xstream JAR into the pom.xml but still its throwing the error. My Maven version is 3.3.9 and Tomcat 8 I'm using.

My pom.xml is

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.in28minutes</groupId>
<artifactId>in28Minutes-first-webapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                    <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

### Error

com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

```
1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/io/HierarchicalStreamDriver
```

at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo

```
1 error
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:517)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/io/HierarchicalStreamDriver
at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.AbstractWarMojo.<init>(AbstractWarMojo.java:316)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.<init>(WarMojo.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:86)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:105)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:89)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:87)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
... 42 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently created a new Maven Projec into Spring Tool Suite, My project is totally new, but I found the same problem.
The problem is the library, when I found problems related with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError I normally try to delete the library in question that is giving problems.

For example, in Windows 7, I go to:

C:\Users\.m2\repository\

next I deleted the "thoughtworks" folder.
Remember you need have closed Eclipse o STS IDE because the program lock the folder and you cant delete the pluging folder.

After delete the folder you can restart your IDE and you need

Maven > "update Project"

This happens sometime with others libraries, sometime they are damaged, sometime not, buy this work and fix this kind of problems.

And ready!

Comment: You don't need add "xstream" explicitly as dependency, I don't have this dependecy in my POM file, but indirectly is used as dependency.